# Нерекурсивная функция печати элементов дерева - обход в глубину

Tags: c++, дерево, бинарное-дерево

Дали задание: Создание BST-дерева методом вставки в лист(рекурсивная реализация). Не рекурсивная функция печати элементов дерева – обход «в глубину». С первой частью задания я справился. Вот код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <Windows.h> 

 struct Node {

    char s[81];

    Node *left, *right;
   Node():left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
   void DestructorWithoutSubTree()
   {
       left = NULL;
       right = NULL;
       delete this;
   }
   ~Node()
   {
       if (left) delete left;
       if (right) delete right;
       left = NULL;
       right = NULL;
   }

};

 class BTree
 {
     Node* root;
     size_t count;
     void Insert(Node *Tree, char *s)
     {
         if (strcmp(s, Tree->s) >= 0)
         {
             if (!Tree->right)
             {
                 Node *n = new Node;
                 strcpy(n->s, s);
                 Tree->right = n;
             }
             else Insert(Tree->right, s);
         }
         else
         {
             if (!Tree->left)
             {
                 Node *n = new Node;
                 strcpy(n->s, s);
                 Tree->left = n;
             }
             else Insert(Tree->left, s);
         }
     }
 public:
     BTree() :root(NULL),count(0) {};
     ~BTree()
     {
         delete root;
         root = NULL;
         count = 0;
    }

     size_t Size()
     {
         return count;
     }
     bool Search(Node *Tree, char *s)
     {
         if (strcmp(s, Tree->s) == 0) return true;
         else if (strcmp(s, Tree->s) > 0)
         {
             if (!Tree->right) return false;
             else return Search(Tree->right, s);

         }
         else
         {
             if (!Tree->left) return false;
             else return Search(Tree->left, s);
         }
     }
     bool Search(char *s)
     {
         return Search(root, s);
     }


     void Insert(char *s)
     {
         if(root)
         Insert(root, s);
         else
         {
             Node *n = new Node;
             strcpy(n->s, s);
             root = n;
         }
         count++;
     }
     Node * FindParent(Node *parent, Node *n)
     {
         if (parent->left == n || parent->right == n) return parent;
         else 
         {
             Node *tmp = new Node;
             tmp = NULL;
             if (parent->left) tmp=FindParent(parent->left, n);
             if (parent->right && !tmp) tmp= FindParent(parent->right, n);
             return tmp;
         }
     }
     Node * FindParent( Node *n)
     {
         return FindParent(root, n);
     }
     void Delete(size_t i)
     {
         Node *n = (*this)[i];
         Node *parent = this->FindParent(n);

             if (!n->left && !n->right)
             {
                 if (parent->left == n) parent->left = NULL;
                 if (parent->right == n) parent->right = NULL;
                 if (!parent) root = NULL;
                 delete n;
             }
             else if ((!n->left) != (!n->right))
             {
                 if (parent->left == n)
                 {
                     if(n->left)
                     parent->left = n->left;
                     else parent->left = n->right;
                 }
                 if (parent->right == n) {
                     if (n->left)
                         parent->right = n->left;
                     else parent->right = n->right;
                 }
                 if (!parent) root = n->left ? n->left : n->right;
                 n->DestructorWithoutSubTree();
             }
             else
             {
                 size_t *ptr = new size_t;
                 *ptr = 0;
                 Node *tmp=this->At(n->right,ptr);//Ищем самый левый элемент правого поддерева нашего узла,для того чтобы заменить им удаляемый узел
                 strcpy(n->s, tmp->s);
                 if (n->right == tmp) n->right = tmp->right;//Если самый левый элемент является нашим правым узлом
                 else FindParent(n, tmp)->left = tmp->right;
                 tmp->DestructorWithoutSubTree();
             }
             count--;

     }

     bool IsEmpty()
     {
         return !root;
     }
     void Show(Node* Tree) {

         if (Tree == NULL) return;
         Show(Tree->left);
         printf("\n%s left=%s right=%s",Tree->s,Tree->left->s,Tree->right->s);
         Show(Tree->right);

     }
     void Show() {
         Show(root);
         printf("\n");
     }
     void ShowElemAt(size_t i)
     {
         printf("\n%s\n",(*this)[i]->s);
     }
     Node *At(Node *p, size_t *n) {

         Node *q;

         if (p == NULL) return NULL;

         q = At(p->left, n);

         if (q != NULL) return q;

         if ((*n)-- == 0) return p;

         return At(p->right, n);

     }
     Node * operator[](size_t n)
     {
         size_t *ptr=new size_t;
         *ptr = n;
         return this->At(root, ptr);
     }

 };



int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    char ch;
    char buf[81];
    BTree bTree;
    do {

        system("cls");

        printf("\n1. Добавить строку в дерево\n2. Показать элемент с заданным индексом");
        printf("\n3. Удалить элемент\n4. Проверить есть ли строка в дереве\n5. Вывести все элементы");
        printf("\n6. Очистить дерево\n0. Выход\n");

        ch = _getch();

        int i;

        switch (ch) {

        case '1':
            printf("\nВведите строку для добавления(80 символов масимум): ");
            fflush(stdin);
            rewind(stdin);
         if(scanf("%80s", buf) != 1)
            {
                printf("\nОшибка Ввода");

            }
         else bTree.Insert(buf);
            break;
        case '2':
            printf("\nВведите индекс(индекс первого элемента=0) строки которую хотите получить:");
            fflush(stdin);
            rewind(stdin);
            if(scanf("%d", &i)!=1)
            {
                printf("\nОшибка Ввода\n");

            }
            else 
            {
                if(bTree[i])
                bTree.ShowElemAt(i);
                else printf("\nЭлемент с данным индексом отсуствует в списке!\n");
            }
            break;
        case '3':
            printf("\nВведите индекс(индекс первого элемента = 0) строки для удаления: ");
            fflush(stdin);
            rewind(stdin);
            if (scanf("%d", &i) != 1)
            {
                printf("\nОшибка Ввода\n");

            }
            else
            {
                if (bTree[i])
                {
                    bTree.Delete(i);
                    printf("\nЭлемент удален\n");
                }
                else printf("\nЭлемент с данным индексом отсуствует в списке!\n");
            }
            break;
        case '4':
            printf("\nВведите строку(регистр учитывается): ");
            fflush(stdin);
            rewind(stdin);
            if (scanf("%80s", buf) != 1)
            {
                printf("\nОшибка Ввода");

            }
            else
            {
                if (bTree.Search(buf)) printf("\nСтрока присутствует в дереве\n");
                else printf("\nСтрока отсуствует в дереве!\n");
            }
            break;
        case '5':

            if (!bTree.IsEmpty()) bTree.Show();
            else  printf("\nДерево пусто\n");
            break;
        case '6':

            bTree.~BTree();
            printf("\nСписок очищен\n");
            break;
        case '0':

            return 0;

        default:
            printf("\nНеизвестная команда,попробуйте еще раз.\n");
            break;

        }

        system("pause");

    } while (1);
    system("PAUSE");





    return 0;
}
```

Но здесь печать массива не та, которая нужна.

```
 void Show(Node* Tree) {

     if (Tree == NULL) return;
     Show(Tree->left);
     printf("\n%s left=%s right=%s",Tree->s,Tree->left->s,Tree->right->s);
     Show(Tree->right);

 }
```

Мне нужно заменить эту функцию печати дерева на другую НЕРЕКУРСИВНУЮ функцию печати дерева, основанную на прямом обходе в глубину (Preorder Traversal non recursive). Не могли бы вы подсказать, как мне сделать это?

Comment: Вот пример функции http://www.sanfoundry.com/cpp-program-perform-preorder-non-recursive-traversal-given-binary-tree/

Comment: дак а в чем проблема у вас ?

Comment: У меня не получается функцию из примера адаптировать под мой код

Comment: Обход такого дерева (указатели только на сыновей) требует рекурсивного алгоритма, который никаким разумным способом не может быть заменен на нерекурсивный. Все, что вы можете сделать, это реализовать рекурсию через явный стек, вместо неявного (как в ответе Lex Hobbit). Однако если вы добавите в узлы дерева ссылки на отцов, сразу же станет возможным нерекурисивный алгоритм обхода. Так что вам можно, а что нельзя делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не мастер в С. Но надеюсь вам это поможет.

Алгоритм должен быть примерно таким:

1. Создаем стек.
2. Печатаем root и помещаем его в стек, идем в левый элемент (root = root->left до тех пор пока не дойдем до NULL).
3. если root == NULL и стек пуст, то мы закончили обход,
   иначе:

   - извлекаем из стека элемент и устанавливаем его как корневой
   - идем в правый элемент (root = root->right)
   - переходим к п.2

.

```
void Show(Node* root) {
    struct stackNode* head = NULL;
    init(head);
    while (true) {
            // печатаем root и добавляем в стек левый элемент
            while (root != NULL) {
                printf("\n%s",root ->s);
                head = push(head, root);
                root = root->left;
            }
            // проверяем пустой ли стек, если да, то выходим
            if (empty(head) == 1) {
                return;
            }
            // извлекаем элемент из стека и делаем то же самое для правого элемента
            head = pop(head, root);
            root = root->right;
        }
   }
```

Так как для работы алгоритма нужен stack, то реализуем его на основе связного списка.

**stack.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stack.h>

struct stackNode
{
    Node* data;
    struct stackNode* next;
};

/*
    init the stack
*/
void init(struct stackNode* head)
{
    head = NULL;
}

/*
    push an element into stack
*/
struct stackNode* push(struct stackNode* head, Node* data)
{
    struct stackNode* tmp = (struct stackNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct stackNode));
    if(tmp == NULL)
    {
        exit(0);
    }
    tmp->data = data;
    tmp->next = head;
    head = tmp;
    return head;
}
/*
    pop an element from the stack
*/
struct stackNode* pop(struct stackNode *head, Node* element)
{
    struct stackNode* tmp = head;
    element = head->data;
    head = head->next;
    free(tmp);
    return head;
}
/*
    returns 1 if the stack is empty, otherwise returns 0
*/
int empty(struct stackNode* head)
{
    return head == NULL ? 1 : 0;
}
```

**stack.h**

```
int empty(struct stackNode *s);
struct stackNode* push(struct stackNode *s,Node *data);
struct stackNode* pop(struct stackNode *s, Node *data);
void init(struct stackNode * s);
```